# Что это значит в конструкторе?

Tags: c++, ооп, конструктор

```
struct Node {
  string val;
  Node* next;
  Node(string _val) : val(_val), next(nullptr){}
};
```

что тут в конструкторе означает эта часть:  `: val(_val), next(nullptr)`???

Comment: Почитайте про списки инициализации (только не перепутайте с std::initializer_list)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Что это такое?

Это вызов конструкторов/инициализаторов для полей класса. Выполняется во время создания экземпляра класса. Конструкторы будут вызваны в том порядке, в каком создаются поля, **а не в том порядке, в каком они перечислены здесь**. Это важно, если при создании имеются зависимости между полями.

2. Зачем это? Ведь я могу просто присвоить нужные значения в теле конструктора?

- Это расточительно. Некоторые объекты создаются и удаляются заметное количество времени, кроме того, если следовать [принципам RAII](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), такое избыточное создание-удаление может создать неоправданную нагрузку на ресурсы.
- Некоторые поля нужно обязательно присвоить прямо при создании. В частности, речь идет о константах и ссылках. Без такого синтаксиса иметь такие поля было бы невозможно.

3. Когда этим пользоваться?

**Всегда.** Нужно как можно шире применять полную инициализацию объектов в конструкторе (опять же, следовать RAII) и недопускать ситуаций, когда объект может находиться в неконсистентном состоянии.